# How can I prevent Hibernate fetching joined entities when I access only the foreign key id?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a Hibernate entity `Parent` that is joined to another: `Child`. In the database I have a column `parent.child_id` that has a foreign key constraint on `child.id`. Assuming I'm lazily loading, when I load an instance of `Parent` I expect to be able to access `parent.getChild().getId()` without incurring a lookup on the `child` table.

I expected the proxy returned by `parent.getChild()` to be able to fulfil a request to `Child.getId()` as it has already loaded the child's id from `parent.child_id` column. However, I see an additional query on the `child` table.

Why is this extra query necessary, and how can I avoid it? In this instance I'm only interested in the foreign key ID, and do not wish to load the whole row.

**Classes:**

```
class Parent {
  @Id @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
  private Child child;
}

class Child {
  @Id @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
}
```

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE parent (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    child_id int REFERENCES (child.id)
);
```

Comment: You have reversed the names Parent/Child in this relationship see this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key
+1 since your question makes sense. I also wanted to get ONLY the foreign key id (that is already present in the table) without actually fetching the row pointed by the foreign key. But hibernate is proving to be a performance nightmare after showing some initial promises of coding time saved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that `Child` uses field access (since annotations are placed on fields), therefore Hibernate simply initializes the proxy when you call any of its methods.

If you move annotations to properies, it would work as expected.

Since JPA 2.0 (Hibernate 3.5) you can configure it in fine-grained way:

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD) // Default is field access
class Child {
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) // Use property access for id
    @Id @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() { ... }

    ...   
}
```