# Lazy Fetch JPA Getting JoinCoulmn MappedBy ID

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Here is the situation

```
      @Entity
      public class Table_A implements Serializable {

      //TABLE_A FIELDS

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_BID")
    public Table_B getTable_B() {
    return table_B;
}
      }
```

So A many to one relationship exist between Table_A and Table_B
My question is when i do a

```
Long tableB_ID = table_A.getTable_B().getTable_BID();
```

In JPA/Hibernate implementation does the fetch get an instance of the TABLE_B and get corrsponding ID from it

or

Gets the ID from the mapped Column?

Thanks in Advance for the answers.

Comment: I think you have an error in your code: `table_A.getTable_B.getTable_BID()` should be `table_A.getTable_B().getTable_BID()`. Please confirm by changing your question that I am right or post a comment if I am wrong.

Comment: you are right. thanks Andrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a Lazy fetch for a relationship it indicates that when you access the object in this case when you call the method getTable_B() in this moment the persistence provider makes a select in the database and fill the object. It behaviour is propietary of the persistence provider in the case of Hibernate it use proxy objects so the fetch is made when you access a field of the related object so getTable_B().getTable_BID(). If you want to access only to the TABLE_BID you can make a JPQL query, or map this field in your Table A, so

```
 @Column(name="TABLE_BID")
 public Long getTable_BID() {
    return table_BID;
}
```

Comment: That's wrong. calling getTableB() doesn't load the state associated with TableB. It simply returns the uninitialized proxy. The state is loaded only when a method is called on the returned proxy.

Comment: That's is not true it depends on how the persistence provider implements it. One way is proxy objects. Technically in JPA LAZY is just a hint, and a JPA provider is not required to support it

Comment: But the OP asked specifically for Hibernate. And Hibernate doesn't do it as you tell in your answer.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer, but I don't mention hibernate in my answer, I wrote persistence provider in general, I don't want to be specific, the question is JPA/Hiberanate

Comment: Getting the value of TABLE_BID  without going to the database because if the entity A is managed it has the value already

Comment: Yes entity A already has the value of TABLE_BID, so fetching it from TableB entity makes no sense. Doesnt  @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_BID") create that mapped column? Also is it required to annotate another column as you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: AFAIR The JPA Specification dont say that @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_BID") create that mapped column, I think if you want to access this column you can make directly to avoid one trip to the database, and yes you need to map another column.

Comment: CésarLoachamin, i think you got your facts wrong. Are you sure  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_BID") does not guarantee a column??

Comment: Maybe I don't undestand the question sorry Maybe my english is not enough, The column is guarantee it exist in the table A, but when you navigate to the relationship entity .getTable_B(), it is dependent of the persistence provider of how to get this values, in hiberante it has a proxy object, maybe if you get the id it don't go to the database, maybe as you get the object it goes and select all the fields, as I said the @JoinColumn don't guarrantee that the value of the join column is loaded, it depends of how the persistence provider manage the lazy fetch.

Comment: Thanks  César Loachamin.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776675/785663): the former.

Hibernate needs to check if the referenced `Table_B` instance still exists, so it has to load the instance before calling `getTable_BID()` on it.

---

**Edit:** Actually, the more interesting question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5351713/785663). And it states that what Hibernate chooses depends on the access type - property access (that's what you have) doesn't initialize the proxy; field access (putting `@ManyToOne`/your `@Id` on a field) initializes the proxy and loads the entity from the database.

Comment: Hibernate knows if the entity exists, because it has the ID of the entity (or null) in the join column.

Comment: @JBNizet I doubt that hibernate knows it: it did not load it because it is lazy, so at that moment it is not sure that it exist. (PS: in DB it can be that there is no foreign key constraint).

Comment: @mabi, please ignore the naming scheme its an abstract name used for the qustion

Comment: @JBNizet jup, should have read the full thing (again); corrected my answer.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, i think that gives a fair idea on how it might behaves . But the thing is the annotations above create a column(TABLE_BID) in TableA, however one need not fetch the id from tableB object when its already available in the loaded TableA object.

Comment: @Andrei: Hibernate expects your schema to be in a coherent state. So if you have an ID in the JoinColumn, then you must have a corresponding row in TableB. If you don't have one, you'll get an exception, unless you use the proprietary [NotFound](docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html) annotation

Comment: @JBNizet exactly. But what I said is that hibernate will know whether that row exists, ONLY when it fetches it. As the relationship is marked lazy, on loading of a Table_A entity (with its relationship to Table_B not loaded) hibernate does not know whether the entity exists (but this is what you wrote in the first comment).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, it depends on the access type, which itself depends on how you annotated your entities. If you annotated the getters, then you're using property access type, and getting the ID won't load the TableB state from the database. If you annotated the fields, then you're using field access type, and getting the ID will load the TableB state.

This is of course implementation-dependant. But you can easily check it by turning SQL logging on, executing your code, and see if a query to load the TableB state is generated or not.

Comment: Thanks, i know we can check it by turning SQL logging on. However i am migrating a whole application which is broken and i dont think i can do that now. So just wanted a idea from experts.